# Angular 2 : Toggle Boolean based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, boolean

I have a search-bar and I want to show all the filtered names when the input value length is 2 or longer.

I managed to get the `value.length` out of the input field. Now I'm stuck.
At first I had done:

```
if (value.length >= 2){
  showNames: true;
}
```

Default `showNames` is false. And when the length was 2 or higher, it set to true. So, that's working. Only when the user erases the text, so the value.length is below 2 again, the boolean won't turn false again. I tried if else, but I know that's not correct in Angular 2.

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getNames($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list *ngIf="showNames">
   <ion-item *ngFor="let name of names">
     {{ name }}
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I know I can toggle a boolean from a button click, but I just want to toggle it from the length of a value.

`*ngIf="value.length >= 2"` doesn't work either, because I create the variable 'value' in my Typescript. So in my HTML it's not defined. And I don't want to use the big formula to calculate the length, that's why I created a variable.

How can I either

1. Pass the variable 'value' from my Typescript to my HTML so I can use the `*ngIf="value.length > 2"`?
2. OR do some kind of If / Else in my Typescript, so I can use a single boolean like `*ngIf="showNames"` in my HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind to the model of the searchbar like this:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (ionInput)="getNames($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list *ngIf="searchValue.length >= 2">
   <ion-item *ngFor="let name of names">
     {{ name }}
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And in your component define such a variable:

```
export class ComponentA {
    searchValue: string = "";

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `showNames` a function and aim to do `*ngIf="showNames()"`, or if it is that short perform the check right there: `*ngIf="value.length >= 2"`